# Pass grouped data.frame using dplyr / magrittr

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

With `base::by()` and `data.table`, we can group by variable(s) and then be able to access a data.frame that is subset by the groups. How can I do the equivalent with [magrittr](/questions/tagged/magrittr) or [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr)?

I tried `tib %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate(V2 = fx(.))` but instead of passing the subgroups, the dot passes the entire grouped `tibble` from the LHS. Here's an MRE:

```r
library(dplyr)
tib = tibble(grp = rep(1:2, 1:2),
             V1 = 1:3)
tib
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     grp    V1
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     2     2
#> 3     2     3

fx = function(x){
  ans = seq(nrow(x))
  print(ans)
}

tib %>%
  group_by(grp)%>%
  mutate(V2 = fx(.))
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `V2`.
#> x Input `V2` can't be recycled to size 1.
#> i Input `V2` is `fx(.)`.
#> i Input `V2` must be size 1, not 3.
#> i The error occured in group 1: grp = 1.
```

And here is the behavior I hoped for using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(tib)[, V2 := fx(.SD), grp][]
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 1 2
#>      grp    V1    V2
#>    <int> <int> <int>
#> 1:     1     1     1
#> 2:     2     2     1
#> 3:     2     3     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cur_data()` from `dplyr` 1.0.0 onwards.

```
library(dplyr)
tib %>% group_by(grp)%>% mutate(V2 = fx(cur_data()))

#[1] 1
#[1] 1 2
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   grp [2]
#    grp    V1    V2
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     1
#2     2     2     1
#3     2     3     2
```

Note that `cur_data()` passes data without grouping variable (`grp`). If you want grouping variable should be passed to the function use `cur_data_all()` instead.